# How to sketch this quadric surface

Tags: graphing-functions, quadrics

I figured out that this quadric surface is one sheeted hyperboloid but I am unable to plot it in the $xy, xz,$ and the $yz$- planes. I have used the approach where we can put the one axis zero and find the points at that plane, but it's not working out for me. I would really appreciate it if someone could please share a detailed solution. Thank you!

Comment: $z^2 = 4x^2 + y^2 + 8x − 2y + 4z \iff z^2-4z=4x^2+8x+y^2-2y \iff(z-2)^2+1=4(x+1)^2+(y-1)^2 $ Does it help?

Comment: Place all the terms in the LHS and consider the result as a quadratic equation in variable $z$, i.e. with $x,y$ as parameters and solve it... this will give you in particular a condition coming from discriminant $\Delta  \ge 0$. Do the same thing by taking this time $x$ as the variable and $y,z$ as the parameters, etc.

Comment: use https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot+3D+z%5E2+%3D+4x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2+%2B+8x+%E2%88%92+2y+%2B+4z

Comment: @Gio Yes, that makes sense, but how do I find the points on the xy, xz, and yz, planes to plot the hyperboloid? The equation you got is the standard form of one sheeted hyperboloid.

Comment: @JeanMarie Hi! Thank you for sharing, but I'm finding it slightly ambiguous. Can you share a more detailed solution for the same?

Comment: `ContourPlot3D[
 z^2 == 4 x^2 + y^2 + 8 x - 2 y + 4 z, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5,
   5}]` shows a hyperboloid of one sheet.

Comment: IIRC, the most recent edit, which removed the equation from the title, leaves only a ghost question....

Answer (score 0):

It can be tricky to visualize three-dimensional surfaces from the equation alone, but plotting in the plane isn't so bad when remember that (e.g.) the XY plane is the set of all points $(x,y,z)$ where $z=0$. This means that on the XY plane, our equation
$$
z^2 = 4x^2 + y^2 + 8x − 2y + 4z
$$
simplifies by setting $z=0$ to
$$
0 = 4x^2 + y^2 + 8x - 2y.
$$
If you have a hard time seeing what shape this should make, you may wish follow the advice in the comments by completing the square and factoring:
$$
0 = 4(x^2 + 2x + 1 - 1) + (y^2 - 2y + 1 - 1)
= 4(x + 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2 - 5.
$$
Rearrange a teeny bit, and we get
$$
5 = 4(x + 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2.
$$
Does this look familiar?

Similarly, the XZ plane is the set of all points $(x,y,z)$ where $y=0$, so we want to plot
$$
z^2 = 4x^2 + 8x + 4z.
$$
Do you see where to go from here? And the same for the YZ plane?

If you get stuck, might I recommend https://www.desmos.com/calculator for checking your two-dimensional graphs. You can also, for example, input the complete three-dimensional equation and show XY slices as a function of $z$.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I got what you're doing, but after the final equation in each of the planes, I am not sure how to find the points to plot my graph because it's not in the standard form of an ellipse. Can you please help me with that? Thank you and I appreciate it.

Comment: The second equation in the xz plane shows a pair of intersecting lines, but shouldn't it be an ellipse?

Answer (score 0):

Here’s how I would attack the problem, but you must check my computations:

\begin{align}
z^2&=4x^2 + y^2 + 8x -2y + 4z\\
z^2-4z&=4(x^2+2x)\quad+\quad(y^2-2y)\\
(z-2)^2-4&=4(x+1)^2-4\quad+\quad(y-1)^2-1\\
\zeta^2&=4\xi^2+\eta^2-1\,,
\end{align}
and I guess that says that you have a hyperboloid of one sheet, center at $(-1,1,2)$.

(I notice belatedly that the first commenter, @Gio, has given you this answer already.)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your approach! Why did you use Riemann zeta, mew, and the Xi letter at the end? Do we use that to sketch the one sheeted hyperboloid? What's the assumption here?

Comment: The zeta that has been used is not a reference to Riemann zeta function; it's just a letter.